# Find local maxima index of element not surrounded by zeros

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to identify the indexes of local maxima not surrounded by zeros of a 1D numpy array.

The original code is:

```
max_idx = [
    i for i in range(1, len(elem_array) - 1)
    if ((elem_array[i - 1] < elem_array[i]) and (elem_array[i + 1] <= elem_array[i]))
    and ((elem_array[i - 1] != 0) or (elem_array[i + 1] != 0))
]
```

With this code using the array:

```
elem_array = np.array([23,  0, 45,  0, 12, 13, 14,  0,  0,  0,  1, 67,  1])
```

the result is: `max_idx = [6, 11]`.

**Important:** the element `i` can be greater or equal to element `i+1`, but just greater than element `i-1` and the `0` can be only in 1 side of the element `i`, this is the reason why `45` is not recognised as a local maximum.

I was trying to modify it with `scipy.signal.argrelextrema`, but this gives me the result: `max_idx = [2, 6, 11]`, which contains an extra element.

And with the array:

```
elem_array = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.07, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
```

the result is an empty array, when it should be: `max_idx = [10]`.

Do you have any suggestion how the original code could be modified? Thanks

Comment: The first value in the array is 23 which is not surrounded by zeros so why isn't the output [0, 6, 11] ?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the code in the first place? time performance?

Comment: @LancelotduLac the code scans the array every 3 elements, so the first sub-array is the one with indexes [0, 1, 2] and it checks if one in the centre, index 1, pass the selection. In So the first and last element of the array are not took in account.

Comment: @FBruzzesi I am cleaning the code, improving the performance, making it more readable and so on, and, for that part, I wanted to find another way to reach the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop like this is pretty straightforward to vectorize:

```python
mask = (
    (elem_array[:-2] < elem_array[1:-1])
    & (elem_array[2:] <= elem_array[1:-1])
    & ((elem_array[:-2] != 0) | (elem_array[2:] != 0))
)
max_idx = np.nonzero(mask)[0] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) to create a sliding window of shape 3 and then apply conditions in vectorized way:

```py
import numpy as np

def get_local_maxima(a: np.array, window_shape: int = 3) -> np.array:
    
    mid_index = window_shape//2
    # Adding initial and final zeros and create the windo of given size
    window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.array([0]*mid_index + [*a] + [0]*mid_index), window_shape)
    
    c1 = np.argmax(window, axis=1)==mid_index # first condition is that the max must be in the center of the window
    c2 = (window[:, [i for i in range(window_shape) if i!=mid_index]]!=0).any(axis=1) # second condition is that one among 0-th and 2-nd element must be non-zero
    
    return np.argwhere(c1 & c2)

a = np.array([23,  0, 45,  0, 12, 13, 14,  0,  0,  0,  1, 67,  1])
b = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.07, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

get_local_maxima(a)
array([[ 6],
       [11]])

get_local_maxima(b)
array([[10]])
```

Comment: This is an interesting numpy function, I have to keep in mind thanks